# Extract data from the return of the module vmware_guest_network

Tags: ansible

Thanks to Ansible and its `vmware_guest_network` module, I extracted data for several VMs, in a variable `vm_info.network_data`, such as:

```yaml
{
    "vm_info.network_data": {
        "0": {
            "allow_guest_ctl": true, 
            "connected": true, 
            "device_type": "VMXNET3", 
            "label": "Network adapter 1", 
            "mac_addr": "xxxxxx", 
            "name": "DVSwitch: xxxxxxx", 
            "start_connected": true, 
            "unit_number": 7, 
            "wake_onlan": true
        }, 
        "1": {
            "allow_guest_ctl": true, 
            "connected": true, 
            "device_type": "VMXNET3", 
            "label": "Network adapter 2", 
            "mac_addr": "rrrrr", 
            "name": "DVSwitch: tttttttt", 
            "start_connected": true, 
            "unit_number": 8, 
            "wake_onlan": true
        }, 
        "2": {
            "allow_guest_ctl": true, 
            "connected": true, 
            "device_type": "VMXNET3", 
            "label": "Network adapter 3", 
            "mac_addr": "xxxxxxxxx", 
            "name": "DVSwitch: vvvvvvvvvv", 
            "start_connected": true, 
            "unit_number": 9, 
            "wake_onlan": true
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to trigger a message for VM not having `start_connected` set as `true`.

But the variable `vm_info.network_data` does not seems to be a list.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  loop: "{{ vm_info.network_data }} | map(attribute='start_connected')|wantlist=True }}"
```

The above is throwing me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not a list, a list of dictionaries, represented in JSON would be:

```json
[ 
  {
    "foo": "foo 1"
    "bar": "bar 1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo 2"
    "bar": "bar 2"
  }
]
```

While what you have is a dictionary where the keys are the string representation of `0`, `1` and `2`, e.g.: `"1"`:

```json
{ 
  "0": {
    "foo": "foo 1"
    "bar": "bar 1"
  },
  "1": {
    "foo": "foo 2"
    "bar": "bar 2"
  }
}
```

The way to loop on a dictionary in Ansible is quite simple, it involves using the [`dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html).

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.value.start_connected }}"
  loop: "{{ vm_info.network_data | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.value.label }}"
```

We get the expected `start_connected` field of all the network adapters:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=Network adapter 1) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=Network adapter 2) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=Network adapter 3) => 
  msg: true
```